# Passing a value Grails

Tags: javascript, html, grails, grails-controller

Im trying to pass a value from a gsp to a controller. But I keep getting undefined as my value.
Im not sure what I am doing wrong here. So I am using this

```
 <selectBox id ="sb" onchange="${remoteFunction(action: 'Report', params: '\'value=\' + this.value')}">
```

Then I have

```
 def Report() {
      def value1 = params["value"]
```

in my controller

If any one can help or point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated. i am new to Grails.

Comment: I have checked and working from my side at grails 2.2.0. why not you use g:select and you should follow the convention i.e lowercase action if required put controller.

Answer (score 0):

your action needs to be

```
def Report = {
    String value = params.value
}
```

but use lower case for action names. Also the action needs to be in the same controller.

Comment: I keep getting undefined tho?

Comment: 1) Try to inspect your requests from your broser. What is the request url you get? 2) try to make request to the `controller/action` manually from browser, what do you get?

Comment: `params.value` and `params['value']` and `params.get('value')` are the same

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by that, but I am accessing the controller anyway because I am using it to display a database table